# solr: SimplePatternSplitTokenizer splitting on literal 't', 'r', 'n' characters

Tags: solr

I have in my schema:

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.SimplePatternSplitTokenizerFactory" pattern="[ \t\r\n]+"/>
</analyzer>
```

This is literally copied and pasted from the solr docs. Now, splitting on the space character works. However, instead of splitting on tab, return carriage, and line feed characters, it splits on the characters 't', 'r', and 'n'. What is going on??

Comment: The \ inside the statement probably escapes the value in the string itself - try `pattern="[ \\t\\r\\n]+"]`

Comment: @MatsLindh That didn't work. Thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below one would work for you.

```
<fieldType name="patternSplit" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.SimplePatternSplitTokenizerFactory" pattern="[&#x9;&#xA;&#xD;]+"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The Lucene's RegExp constructor consumes raw unicode characters instead of
\t\r\n form, so correct configuration is

```
<tokenizer class="solr.SimplePatternSplitTokenizerFactory" pattern="[ &#x9;&#xA;&#xD;]+"/>
```

Please find the screenshot from the analysis page.

[image: sc1]

[image: sc2]